# How to change file's metadata in Google Cloud Storage with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

My image's (which is hosted in Google Cloud Storage) metadata has the property named `downloaded`, if the image has been downloaded, the value inside the `downloaded` key will be changed from `0` to `1`.

The code in https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#storage-view-object-metadata-nodejs shows how to view the metadatas but didn't really cover how to change the metadata.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

The way to do it is by using the [`File.setMetadata()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#setMetadata) method.

For example, to add metadata to an object in GCS:

```
const file = storage
        .bucket(bucketName)
        .file(filename)

const metadata = {
        metadata: {
                example: 'test'
        }
}

file.setMetadata(metadata)

// Get the updated Metadata
const get_metadata =  file.getMetadata();

// Will print `File: test`
console.log(`File: ${metadata.metadata.example}`)
```

To update it, you can retrieve the current metadata with the [`getMetadata()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getMetadata) method, modifying it, and updating it with the [`setMetadata()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#setMetadata) method .

For example:

```
const storage = new Storage();

const file = storage
        .bucket(bucketName)
        .file(filename)

// Get the file's metadata 
const [metadata] = await file.getMetadata()

console.log(`File: ${metadata.name}`)

// update metadata    
file.setMetadata(metadata.metadata.example='updated')


// Get the updated metadata
const [get_metadata] = await file.getMetadata()
console.log(`File: ${get_metadata.metadata.example}`)
```